# Stub model in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, view, rspec, specifications

I wan't to write spec for a view in Rails with Rspec. I wrote this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "homepage/index.html.erb" do
  it 'has list of publications with id #publications' do
    render
    expect(rendered).to have_selector('ul#publications')
  end

  it 'has publications on the list' do
    assign(:publications, [
      stub_model(Publication, content: 'First publication.'),
      stub_model(Publication, content: 'Second publication.')
    ])
    render
    rendered.should have_content('First publication.')
    rendered.should have_content('Second publication.')
  end
end
```

But `stub_model` seems to be not working.

```
rspec
.....F.

Failures:

  1) homepage/index.html.erb has list of publications with id #publications
     Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/homepage/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_homepage_index_html_erb___3273264012123365698_43368240'
     # ./spec/views/homepage/index.html.erb_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.17634 seconds
7 examples, 1 failure
```

How can I stub this properly?

Comment: I downvoted your question because you did not provide the relevant code of your `index.html.erb`.

Comment: I thought it was obvious... but anyway I asked too fast. Failing test was the first one, not the second. So I moved assign to `before` and works great.

Answer (score 1):

The description given in your failure message indicates that your failing on the example *above* the example with the stubs. In that example, nothing has been assigned to the instance variable `@publications`, so the view is presumably raising the error you're seeing as a result of executing `@publications.each ...`.

But as @phoet implied, you really should provide the code that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is a good idea to stub models in such (integration or acceptance) tests.

But if you would like to do it you should stub query to DB (when you are trying to stub assigns). For example you have `Publication.all` in your action - so you can stub

```
Publication.stub(all:
  [
    stub_model(Publication, content: 'First publication.'),
    stub_model(Publication, content: 'Second publication.')
  ])
```